# inappbrowser ios vertical scroll not working

Tags: ios, ionic3, inappbrowser

I’ve created an extremely simple app based on the blank starter template that just wraps a website using InAppBrowser (Ionic 3).

Using Android Studio via a virtual device, the app works as expected - the browser allows me to scroll a page vertically to read content therein.

However, using the Ionic DevApp on iOS 11.4.1 (iPhone) the page loads, but does not let me scroll vertically -it appears to be locked when I swipe up/down.

Here’s my code:

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <ion-title>
      InAppBrowser Test
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
Waiting for InAppBrowser content...
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from "@ionic-native/in-app-browser";
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  constructor(
    private iab: InAppBrowser,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {
      const iabOptions: InAppBrowserOptions = {
        clearcache: 'yes',
        clearsessioncache: 'yes',
        hideurlbar: 'yes',
        location:'no',
        zoom:'no'
      }
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        const browser = this.iab.create('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)','_self', iabOptions);
        browser.show();
      });
    }
}
```

**Ionic Info**

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v6.11.2
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I have also logged a bug in git repo:

[github bug link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/392)